# Why ASP.NET doesn't excute query that SQL Server Management Studio does?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a query:

```
SELECT BookID, BookName, Author, Price, PublishYear, b.categoryName AS Category 
FROM BOOKS a JOIN category b ON a.categoryID = b.categoryID 
WHERE b.categoryID = @category
ORDER BY a.BookID
```

With `@category = myDropDownList.SelectedValue.ToString();`
I sometime want to display some books from different categories, sometime I want to display all books in all categories. When I try to display in 1 category, it does execute query, but when I try to display all, I try to give @category a value equals to "b.categoryID" (it comes from DropDownList too), my query now is:

```
SELECT BookID, BookName, Author, Price, PublishYear, b.categoryName AS Category 
FROM BOOKS a JOIN category b ON a.categoryID = b.categoryID 
WHERE b.categoryID = b.categoryID
ORDER BY a.BookID
```

I've tried to run this query in SSMS, it does execute. But in ASP.NET, it doesn't. Anyone have a solution please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you don't get the query you think you get.
The condition you actually get from the ASP.Net is `WHERE b.categoryID = 'b.categoryID'`. obviously this will not execute correctly.

Try this:

```
SELECT BookID, BookName, Author, Price, PublishYear, b.categoryName AS Category 
FROM BOOKS a JOIN category b ON a.categoryID = b.categoryID 
WHERE b.categoryID = 
    CASE WHEN @category = 'b.categoryID' 
        THEN b.categoryID 
        ELSE @category 
    END
ORDER BY a.BookID
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that if you set `@category` to the string "b.categoryID" then it will result in a query like `Where b.categoryID = 'b.categoryID'`.  Basically you cannot pass in the name of a column or table via a parameter.  Instead you can make the query dynamic.

```
string query = "SELECT BookID, BookName, Author, Price, PublishYear, b.categoryName AS Category " +
               "FROM BOOKS a JOIN category b ON a.categoryID = b.categoryID " + 
               (filter ? "WHERE b.categoryID = @category " : "") +
               "ORDER BY a.BookID";
```

Where `filter` is a `bool` variable that determines if you want to include the where clause.  You should additionally put a `if(filter)` around the code that creates and adds the `@category` parameter to the `SqlCommand`.

Comment: You are assuming that the select statement is a part of the c# code. 
While your solution will work if that is the case, the OP didn't specify that and it may be that it's a stored procedure that the c# simply executes. My solution is good for both cases.